# Low battery warning threshold

Tags: macos, battery

At the moment, my MacBook (Monterey) seems to only alert low battery at the 15% point. Is there any way to change the trigger threshold to 30%? I am aware of third party apps, but I would just like to know if there are some native settings that is already available for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any configuration you get to set on the system itself. Asking Apple support would be a way to get an authoritative answer, but something like that people would love and share here I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, on standard macOS, Apple did not give you the option to change the trigger for low battery notification.

However, you can use the free app called [Battery Monitor](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/battery-monitor-health-info/id836505650?mt=12), which gives you that option.